# Copy schema on postgres with sql not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, multi-tenant

I have multitenancy application on postgres and for create account I copy a schema "template" and rename this for account data.

I use the "sql" var to copy schema "_template".
When I execute this, all works fine, but the column that has the DEFAULT attribute is not replaced.
but when executed sql direct in pgAdmin works fine.

Example:
    "id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('**_template.table_id_seq**'::regclass)"
    this _template.table_id_seq...  should be **[schemaname]**.table_id_seq

```
String sql = new String(
"DO " +
"$do$ " +
"DECLARE " +
"   objeto text; " +
"   buffer text; " +
"   source_schema text; " +
"   dest_schema text; " +
"   default_ text; " +
"   column_ text; " +
"BEGIN " +
" " +
"   source_schema := '_template'; " +
"   dest_schema   := '" + schema + "'; " +
" " +
"EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || dest_schema ; " +
" " +
"   FOR objeto IN " +
"       SELECT sequence_name::text FROM information_schema.SEQUENCES WHERE sequence_schema = source_schema " +
"   LOOP " +
"EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || dest_schema || '.' || objeto; " +
"   END LOOP; " +
" " +
" " +
"   FOR objeto IN " +
"       SELECT table_name::text FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = source_schema " +
"   LOOP         " +
"       buffer := dest_schema || '.' || objeto; " +
"       EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || buffer || ' (LIKE ' || source_schema || '.' || objeto || ' INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING DEFAULTS)'; " +
"FOR column_, default_ IN " +
"           SELECT column_name::text, REPLACE( column_default::text, source_schema, dest_schema ) FROM " +
"               information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = source_schema AND table_name = objeto AND column_default LIKE 'nextval(%' || source_schema || '%)' " +
"       LOOP " +
"EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || buffer || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_ || ' SET DEFAULT ' || default_; " +
"       END LOOP; " +
" " +
"   END LOOP; " +
"END " +
"$do$    " 
);
```

Here an example of a sql var output

```
DO $do$ 
DECLARE     
    objeto text;    
    buffer text;    
    source_schema text;     
    dest_schema text;   
    default_ text;  
    column_ text; 
BEGIN  
    source_schema := '_template';   
    dest_schema   := 'schemacopied';  

    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || dest_schema ;   

    FOR objeto IN       
        SELECT sequence_name::text FROM information_schema.SEQUENCES WHERE sequence_schema = source_schema 

    LOOP 
        EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || dest_schema || '.' || objeto;     
    END LOOP;       

    FOR objeto IN       
        SELECT table_name::text FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = source_schema   
    LOOP                
        buffer := dest_schema || '.' || objeto;         
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || buffer || ' (LIKE ' || source_schema || '.' || objeto || ' INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING DEFAULTS)'; 

        FOR column_, default_ IN            
            SELECT column_name::text, REPLACE( column_default::text, source_schema, dest_schema ) FROM 
            information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = dest_schema AND table_name = objeto AND column_default LIKE 'nextval(%' || source_schema || '%)'        

        LOOP 
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || buffer || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_ || ' SET DEFAULT ' || default_;         
        END LOOP;   
    END LOOP; 
END $do$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nextval(...)` expressions refered to in `information_schema.COLUMNS.column_default` are dynamically generated to include or exclude the schema name depending on the current `search_path`.

If the sequence's schema is not in `search path`, the schema appears as a prefix to the sequence name, otherwise it does not.

Therefore the result of this clause, true or false:

`column_default LIKE 'nextval(%' || source_schema || '%)'`

really depends on `search_path`, which may explain why it works in certain contexts (your test in pgAdmin) and not in others.

To not depend on it, you may force `search_path` for the duration of the block, as in:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  SET LOCAL search_path TO public;
  ...
  ...
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or maybe you could set `search_path` to the source schema and possibly in this case there wouldn't be any post-processing at all required for these schema-related `default` clauses.